# How do I create index on pyspark df?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have bunch of hive tables. 
I want to:

1. Pull the tables into a pyspark DF.
2. Do a UDF on them.
3. Join 4 tables based on customer id.

Is there a concept of indexing in spark to speed up the operation?

- If so whats the command?
- How do I create index on dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem but the thing is, you acquire the data at the same time you process them. Therefore, calculating an index before joining is useless as it will take take more time to first create the index.

If you have several write operation, you may want to cache your data to speed up but otherwise, the index is not the solution to investigate.

There is maybe another thing you can try : `df.repartition`.
This will create partition on your df according to one column. But I have no idea if it can help.

Comment: escuse my ignorance but if you index them thats an operation of O(n) followed by an O(n) to join if I dont join it will take O(n^2) for each join. so woudnt indexing speed it up?

Can you explain how cache can help?

Comment: regarding caching, it is only useful if you perform several write operations. do you ?

Comment: Regarding join, you can read this : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by write? I run 1 or 2 UDF on each table(3 of them) to either manipulate a column or create a new one. Then I join

Comment: @user1871528 then what do you do witht the final df ?

Comment: @user1871528 I edited my post, added `repartition` method. Maybe you can try it.